# Zabbix Error "Get value from agent failed: ZBX_TCP_READ() failed: [104] Connection reset by peer"

Tags: zabbix

I've linked my Zabbix Console to a list of Windows agents, but some of them give me this error "Get value from agent failed: ZBX_TCP_READ() failed: [104] Connection reset by peer".

I've already checked firewall rules and they are all done, as well as checked that the port that I need is opened in Windows Defender. With a telnet from the server to the agent this is the result:

[Telnet Error from Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqLg4.png)

Otherwise, the telnet tried from the agent to the server does not work.

Can you help to locate the error?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you set Server in zabbix_agent2.conf correctly?
You can bind port 10050 to all interfaces with Server=0.0.0.0/0.
Also if you get timeout you can increase timeout with Timeout option in config.